# CSS Properties to remove spacing

Tags: html, css

First I admit, I know CSS but not a master of that.

I have to show 4 images in a table (td). Image placement is required as follow

```
A B
C D
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` & `D` are 4 images with no spacing between them. Width of `TD` is 40 px and of each image is 20px.

I find other questions on Stackoverflow and played with `table's` border-spacing, border-collapse properties to remove space. But now problem is I'm getting my images as

```
A
B
C
D  //without spacing with display:block in `td img`
```

or

```
A B
      //With space, with display:inline-block on `td img`
C D
```

Working demo is given on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/)

Code (HTML)

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" width="40px">
        <img width="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="a">
        <img width="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="b">
        <img width="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="c">
        <img width="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="d">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Code (CSS)

```
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
}
tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
td {
    display: inline-table;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td img {
    display: block;
}
```

What CSS properties should I change to make [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/) as expected.

Comment: use image in diffrent td

Comment: I just gave a part of a big page. There are already other row/columns. So rows might not work.

Comment: You should make your question shorter. I doubt it will be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `float:left to` the td img class

updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/6/

New demo http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/14/

Comment: Thats best so far, but isn't there any way without using float property. I just give a part of my page but there are many row/col and whole table is in div with float:right;

Comment: You can. check the new fiddle without float:left

Answer (score 2):

You can either float them , or align them vertically with inline-block display

```
td img {
    float:left;    
}
```

[Float](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/59vGe/7/)

```
td img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;    
}
```

[Vertical Align](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/59vGe/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Used give to `font-size:0;` in your **td**  and **remove** `display:block;` in your **img** tag

as like this

```
      td {
        display: inline-table;
        border-spacing: 0px;
font-size:0; //add this line
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }td img {
    display:block; // remove this line
        }
```

***[Upated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/10/)***

Comment: In your example, images are in single line. I need them in square format.

Comment: @KapilSharma than remove to white-space in td demo link is http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/10/

Comment: @KapilSharma check my upadated answer and deom link is  http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/10/

Comment: Great. font-size: 0; in td did that I guess. Thanks. Never though font-size apply to images too (LOL/headbang)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/2/)

I used a combination of `float:left` `clear:left` `:nth-child()` and `display:table-cell`

If you can modify the HTML for this you can ad an class attribute to the `td` element like so: `<td class="image-grid">`

and then update the CSS to select specifically for that:

```
td.image-grid img {
    float:left;
    display: block;
}

td.image-grid img:nth-child(3){
    clear:left;
}
```

​

Comment: Isn't there any way without using float property. I just give a part of my page but there are many row/col and whole table is in div with float:right;

Answer (score 0):

Float the images.

```
td img {
    float:left;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59vGe/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use float . but please don't give for all td . instead of that you can give particular class name .

```
.testclass td img {
float:left;    
}
```

It will apply to the testclass td only. it will not affect other table td values.